# How to split date with specific range in pandas or python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following data start date and end date , want to write a function which split the date on below condition

1:split with 3 months interval .if the last split is less than 2 months .. add the date range to previous split (ex: 4th split should be 2018-08-01 to 2018-09-23 and as its less then 2 month so it added to previous row )

```
function should be like 
def (start_date=none ,end_date= none)


ex: if Start_date= 17-01-01 end_date -2018-09-23  
Start_date   end_date    
2017-01-01   2017-03-31
2017-04-01   2017-06-31
2018-06-01   2018-09-23
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear. Can you read through your question and see if you are explaining what you needed clearly?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use **dateutil** library to find the 2 month difference between dates and **datetime** library to define date objects.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

Assuming the inputs are datetime objects

```
start_date = datetime.date(2017,1,1)
end_date = datetime.date(2018,8,23)
```

I created a list to track the start dates of all intervals.

```
ls = []
```

I am gonna append the start_date to the list and update the start_date variable with 3 month increase using a while loop.

Break the loop when you find end_date is less than 2 months plus your next start_date using the **relativedelta** function.

You can see the **if** condition is written after the start_date update.

```
while True:
    ls.append(start_date)
    start_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=3)
    if end_date < start_date + relativedelta(months=2):
        break
    if start_date > end_date:
        break
```

Now except for the last element, print the current start_date and 1 day less than the next start_date.
And for last element, print the start_date and the end_date.

```
print('start_date','end_date')
for i in range(len(ls)-1):
    print(ls[i],ls[i+1]-datetime.timedelta(days=1))
print(ls[-1],end_date)
```

Output:

```
start_date end_date
2017-01-01 2017-03-31
2017-04-01 2017-06-30
2017-07-01 2017-09-30
2017-10-01 2017-12-31
2018-01-01 2018-03-31
2018-04-01 2018-08-23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='20180301', end='20180311'))
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['dates'])

df = df['dates'].groupby(np.arange(len(df['dates']))//3).agg(['first', 'last'])
df
```

Output:

```
       first    last
0   2018-03-01  2018-03-03
1   2018-03-04  2018-03-06
2   2018-03-07  2018-03-09
3   2018-03-10  2018-03-11
```